# Percentage to Std-Deviation Calculator

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, density-function

This is such a useful function, and it should be possible if not analytically, then through a spline and lookup tables.

How does one, in practical terms, go from percentage to standard deviations on a continuous basis?

I.e.:

````
f(68) = 1
f(95) = 2
f(99.7) = 3
f(60) = ?
f(62) = ?

# what is the function f
def f(pct: float): 
    return ??? guassian-pdf? cdf? cdf^-1?
```
````

Comment: Assuming a normal distribution, the R function qnorm(percentile) does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the quantile function, i.e., `qnorm()` in R. It is the inverse of the cumulative density function, i.e., `pnorm()`, also known as the distribution function.

In python, the quantile function exists within `scipp.stats` as `norm.ppf()`.